# UIbutton partially transparent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

[image]

I want a customized button with my own background. The thing is, though I've set the background of the PNG file to transparent, the transparent part was still included in xcode, showing the bigger border. Any idea to solve this problem?  In this simple demo I need the black part only. I created this button in xib, and imageView has this problem too. Thanks.

Comment: how did you set image on button .. Background image or set Image?

Comment: In nib, using the inspector attribute "Background:"

Comment: can you Provide your code here?

Comment: I'm not creating this button with code. I just added it in storyboard.

Comment: put Screenshot of storyboard

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyct3.png

Comment: you can set not background image but set to Image only

Comment: Still showing the border.  :-(

Comment: Make sure your file is a PNG file and that it has an alpha channel using the Finder's get info

Comment: Yes it does . It's so weird.

Comment: I don't know why but I have a feeling that your file is psd format with a png extension

Comment: you can check it with new image @FongTinyik just try to add new image instead of black image for Check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the background image of the button, it took the PNG file you chose and made that the background image.  If you have alpha (transparent) space on your PNG file, it still counts as pixels adding to the size of your image.  They're just clear pixels.  You'll need to edit your PNG file to be just the black part that you want, removing the alpha.

A tip, when making custom buttons with background images, click off of the button to deselect it, then click the button to select it again (Just to make sure.  After you select a file, even though the button looks selected, your hotkeys are affecting the attribute inspector, not the button), then hit cmd + =.  This will auto size the button to be the size of the image that you added as the background image.  If you don't do this, you'll probably see distorted images, since the default is to change the aspect to fill the button's image view.

Comment: @Mayank Patel,@Leonardo Savio Dabus. I see. So is there any method to prevent clear pixels from adding to the size of image? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FongTinyik You can use Preview app in MAC, it has basic editing options for images, If you have image with transparent border, you can select the actual image with selectable rect, copy it (Edit Menu->Copy) and create a new file from File menu -> New from clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Set the opaque flag on the button to false.